# Why do we need the fundamental theorem of calculus to solve this line integral?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading [Conway's complex analysis book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=9LtfZr1snG0C&printsec=frontcover&hl=pt-BR&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) and on page 63 the author uses the fundamental theorem of calculus to solve the line integral:

[image]

Using the theorem 1.9 (see below) of the same book, in order to solve this integral we only need to make a simple substitution $\gamma'(t)=b-a$ in the integrand. I didn't understand where the author is using the fundamental theorem of calculus.

> **Theorem 1.9.** If $\gamma$ is piecewise smooth and $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb C$ is continuous then
>   $$\int_a^bfd\gamma=\int_a^bf(t)\gamma'(t)dt$$

Comment: Theorem 1.9 should have $\int_{a}^b f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)\,dt$ on the right. $f(t)$ is wrong.

Comment: Wait, your statement of Theorem 1.9 is confusing. What is $[a,b]$ when $a,b$ are complex? Isn't $\gamma$ only defined on $[0,1]$, not $[a,b]$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews in this chapter Conway wants $[a,b]\subset \mathbb R$

Comment: Then Theorem 1.9 is irrelevant to the question at the top - it only applies to $\gamma$ with range in $\mathbb R$ as well.

Comment: Basically, your statement of Theorem 1.9 is woefully inadequate. What is $\gamma$? What is its domain and range? I think that 1.9 appears to be using $a,b,\gamma$ entirely differently, so you have to be careful. Names can be similar and still not be related.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental theorem comes in because, when the integrand is analytic and has an antiderivative, the integral depends only on the endpoints and not on the path between them.  This is true even in the context of real functions where the only path taken is the real line - the integral depends only on the endpoints and not on any points in between.  You will note that, when there is a dependence on $\bar{z}$ in the integrand, there is a path dependence and the fundamental theorem does not apply.

Comment: It's not clear for me. The path is already defined.

Comment: Perhaps the author is using the fundamental theorem to say something about the integral that results from using the parametric form of the defined path - that, even with this complicated-looking integrand, we still get the simple result on the RHS.

Comment: It's very strange his comment.  He has never used the TFC in the previous examples. It was the first time he is using TFC to solve line integrals.